# Closing Plink window with Python

Tags: python, telnet, plink

I want to communicate with a data-logger via Telnet. Therefore, I wrote the following python-script:

```
import subprocess

command ='plink.exe -telnet -P 23 12.17.46.06'

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=False)

answer =  p.communicate('command')[0]
print answer
```

By running the script, a plink-windows pops up. The python script seems to wait for some action to be done inside the plink command window. By closing the window manually, the desired "answer" shows up inside python.

I am looking for a command / procedure to close plink directly out of python. It seems not to be sufficient to just close the subprocess, as in this case only the communication between python and plink gets closed and not the program plink.exe itself.

Any help is appreciated!
Regards, Phil

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function says:  *Wait for process to terminate.*  Thus the function does not return until plink.exe exits and thus your program doesn't get the output until then.

You should add to your `'command'` something that will close the telnet connection.  When the far end closes the telnet connection plink.exe will exit and its window will close.  If your telnet session runs a unix shell you could add '; exit' to your command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regardinf the communicate()-command. However, the question remains how to exit plink directly from python. The python script runs on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Your question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  plink will exit when the connection is closed. How will you know *when* to kill it? You can kill it, if you want, by calling [`.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill). Of course, your program can't do anything while it is blocked waiting for the process to terminate. You will either want to learn multithreading (which is very difficult to do without bugs) or provide a timeout to communicate() or use a non-blocking approach to managing the pipe.

Comment: Okay, then I have to re-formulate my problem: How can I kill the telnet connection established by plink **with python**? Your suggestion regarding a timeout would by sufficient for me. However, as I mentioned before, I can terminate the conenction from python to plink, but not the telnet connection of plink itself.

Comment: You kill the process by calling [`.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) on it, as I noted in my previous comment. When the process does not exist, neither will its connection.

Comment: Adding .kill() did not change anything. Plink-window remains open.

Comment: Where in your code did you put the call to `.kill()`?

Comment: Just before "print answer"

Comment: Yeah, that is too late for it to change anything. Before your program can reach that line of code to kill the process, the plink process would have already terminated. When you call .communicate(), your program will wait for plink to exit before it can do anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! What would you suggest where to put the .kill()-command?

Comment: Try moving the call to .kill() before the call to .communicate() to see what happens then. It might help you to understand what I wrote in my my answer (*the function does not return until plink.exe exits*), again in my comment on Mar 23 (*Of course, your program can't do anything while it is blocked waiting for the process to terminate.*) and again on Mar 27 (*When you call .communicate(), your program will wait for plink to exit before it can do anything else.*)

Comment: You need to either accept that you should put an exit command at the end of what you send to the remote system, or you need to use a different method of sending the command and reading the output from the process so that you can identify when you have received the response and can then kill it.  .communicate() can only be used when the process will exit on its own when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your task within plink tunnel is complete and then execute
taskkill within your script

something like,
    killProg=`taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq plink.exe"`
    p.communicate('killProg')[0]

That will kill plink while keeping the tunnel open to execute other commands.